# How to create a simple shadowDOM in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to create a shadowDOM like the following but it is blocking the entire page and displaying the shadowDOM:

```
var host = document.activeElement;
var root = host.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'div';
div.innerHTML = '<style>.div{position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding: 0; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);}</style>this is shadow dom';
root.appendChild(div);
```

how to create a shadowDOM that appears below the current HTML element?

Comment: Good information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

Comment: That causes the above problem: blocking the entire page.

Comment: **The activeElement read-only property of the Document interface returns the Element within the DOM that currently has focus, <body> or null if there is no focused element.**  What has focus when this runs?

Comment: It is blocking the page even if I use ```queryselector('div')```